# Error inflating fragment with lockview, app crashed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I don't know why but my app crashed when it tried to load a fragment that contains a pinlockview that will show up in onResume event. I tried loading the fragment before with only a textview and it works but after I put some code about lockview the app crashed when the activity is accessed.

Activity that uses fragment:

```
package com.amethyst.secretgarden;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver;
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.shashank.sony.fancytoastlib.FancyToast;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleObserver {

    private TextView usernameTv, emailTv;
    private Button toChangePwPage;

    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String userid, email, password, newPassword, confirmPassword;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Boolean previouslyInBackground;

    //fragment
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private Fragment pinFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        //implements "LifeCycleObserver" in class then add this owner to get the lifecyle for onstop when app in background
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);

        usernameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userUsername);
        emailTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userEmail);

        toChangePwPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showLayoutBtn);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarSettings);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        //check if user is signed in or not
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            if (isOnline()) {
                // User is signed in
                showUserInfo();
            }
        } else {
            // No user is signed in
            Toast.makeText(this, "User is not signed in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // beginning hide it first, to start it on onresume if pin is set
        pinFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSettings);
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.hide(pinFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    private void showUserInfo() {

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("main").document(userId).collection("userinfo").document("account");

        userRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                String usernameValue = documentSnapshot.getString("username");
                String emailValue = documentSnapshot.getString("email");

                if (usernameValue == null || usernameValue.isEmpty()) {
                    usernameValue = "Username not available";
                } else if (emailValue == null || emailValue.isEmpty()) {
                    emailValue = "Email not available";
                }
                usernameTv.setText(usernameValue);
                emailTv.setText(emailValue);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Showing Account Info: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public void toChangePasswordPage(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ChangePasswordActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    public void sendEmail(View view) {
        if (isOnline()) {
            //startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, SupportFormActivity.class));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:marinegreen999@gmail.com")); // only email apps should handle this
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    public void toDeleteActivity(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, DeleteAccountActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public void logoutDialog(View view) {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked, log out
                        RelativeLayout byeGifLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.animationLayoutSettings);
                        byeGifLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //delay
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, 2500);
                        break;
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //"No" button clicked
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure that you want to log out of this app?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo == null || !netInfo.isConnected() || !netInfo.isAvailable()) {
            FancyToast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please check your connection and try again", FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //check if user exists or not
        if (user == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Account error: Please log in and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void toSetPasswordPage(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

   /* public void showBtnsLayout(View view) {
        LinearLayout btnLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lockBtnLayout);
        Button lockBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changeLockBtn);
        lockBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void toPatternPage(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, PatternActivity.class));
        finish();
    }*/

    public void toPinPage(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, PinActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public void toEditAccInfoPage(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, EditAccountInfoActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public void showInfoPage(View view) {

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    public void appInResumeState() {

        if (previouslyInBackground == null) {
            //this is needed to prevent it crash
        } else if (previouslyInBackground) {
            //show pin
            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            userid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DocumentReference pinRef = db.collection("main").document(userid).collection("userinfo").document("pin");

            pinRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        pinFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSettings);
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.show(pinFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    } else {
                        pinFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSettings);
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.hide(pinFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Loading pin error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        previouslyInBackground = false;
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void appInStopState() {
        previouslyInBackground = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        previouslyInBackground = false;
    }

}

/*userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            String usernameValue = document.getString("username");
                            String emailValue = document.getString("email");

                            if (usernameValue.isEmpty()) {
                                usernameValue = "Username not available";
                            } else if (emailValue.isEmpty()) {
                                emailValue = "Email not available";
                            }
                            usernameTv.setText(usernameValue);
                            emailTv.setText(emailValue);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "No data exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
```

fragment in activity xml:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.amethyst.secretgarden.PinFragment" />
```

fragment class:

```
package com.amethyst.secretgarden;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.andrognito.pinlockview.IndicatorDots;
import com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockListener;
import com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PinFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PinFragment extends Fragment {

    private PinLockView pinLockView;
    private IndicatorDots indicatorDots;

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private CollectionReference userinfoRef;
    private DocumentReference pinRef;

    private String userid, typedPin, savedPin;
    private RelativeLayout parentLayout;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public PinFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /* Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment using the provided parameters.
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PinFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PinFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PinFragment fragment = new PinFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pin, container, false);

        pinLockView = (PinLockView) getView().findViewById(R.id.pinlockviewFragment);
        indicatorDots = (IndicatorDots) getView().findViewById(R.id.indicator_dotsFragment);
        parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.parentFragment);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userid = user.getUid();

        userinfoRef = db.collection("main").document(userid).collection("userinfo");
        pinRef = userinfoRef.document("pin");

        //attach dots to keypad
        pinLockView.attachIndicatorDots(indicatorDots);

        pinRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    //if pin exists, compare typed pin with saved pin
                    savedPin = documentSnapshot.getString("code");
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pin Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        //pin view, get pin
        pinLockView.setPinLockListener(new PinLockListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String pin) {
                typedPin = pin;

                if (typedPin.equals(savedPin)) {
                    //disappear layout
                    parentLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    clearPin();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong pin, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onEmpty() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPinChange(int pinLength, String intermediatePin) {

            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    public void clearPin() {
        pinLockView.resetPinLockView();
        typedPin = null;
    }

}
```

fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient5"
    tools:context=".PinFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icebox_arthurblack_transparent" />

        <com.andrognito.pinlockview.IndicatorDots
            android:id="@+id/indicator_dotsFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_20sdp" />

        <com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView
            android:id="@+id/pinlockviewFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
            app:dotSpacing="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:keypadTextColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
2020-06-24 16:10:33.080 15339-15339/com.amethyst.secretgarden E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amethyst.secretgarden, PID: 15339
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amethyst.secretgarden/com.amethyst.secretgarden.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #308: Binary XML file line #308: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #308: Binary XML file line #308: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #308: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.PinFragment.onCreateView(PinFragment.java:90)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:358)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:284)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:263)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:800)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:844)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.amethyst.secretgarden.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7337)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7328)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3296)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:114)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:74)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:500)
2020-06-24 16:10:33.081 15339-15339/com.amethyst.secretgarden E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:913)
```

Can someone please help? I tried looking for answers but none that I have seen seemed to solve the issue for this case :( Thank you in advance

Comment: `getView()` will return null in `onCreateView()`. You need to call `findViewById()` on the `View view` that you just inflated above; e.g., `pinLockView = (PinLockView) view.findViewById(R.id.pinlockviewFragment);`.

Comment: @MikeM.Thanks so much, now it loads!